# Substring erro: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

Não consegui entender como funciona o cálculo de `substring` em c#;

A variável abaixo contém 150 caracteres, utilizo o `substring` para receber uma parte dela, mas ocorre uma exceção mesmo estando dentro do alcance. 
Como funciona os parâmetros do `substring`?

```
string conteudo = "Morbi laoreet congue eros, eu elementum lacus dapibus sit amet. Praesent scelerisque, sapien ut efficitur dapibus, ante ligula aliquam lorem, in faucibus ante tortor ac turpis. Fusce lobortis enim ac dui sodales, suscipit ultricies odio dapibus. Sed semper sapien eu tortor imperdiet dapibus. Nunc dictum pellentesque nisi, ac posuere felis luctus in. Sed eu est quis massa pretium condimentum vel sed justo. Aliquam pellentesque in tellus at tristique.";

conteudo.Substring(70,100); //erro
```

Comment: O único erro que vi no seu código é a falta do `;` no final da primeira linha.

Comment: Só utilizei esse código como exemplo